# use .htaccess to rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the rewrite in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule photos/([a-zA-Z]{1,}).([a-zA-Z]{1,}).([0-9]{1,}) photo.php?userfirstname=$1&userlastname=$2&usernum=$3
```

When the url is `www.xxx.com/photos/mark.stock.1` it can go to `photo.php`. I use smarty as the masterplate & everything works well if the url is `www.xxx.com/photo.php` but not like `www.xxx.com/photos/mark.stock.1`

I user the firebug to check the process,found out all the css file and javascript file the url looks like `www.xxx.com/photos/js/xxx.js` or `www.xxx.com/photos/css/xxx.css`
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Replace the `.` with either `\.` or `[.]`

Comment: You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`